# Using LIKE To search for words with no spaces

Tags: sql

I know I've done this before but can't recall basically I have to search for rows that do not contain any spaces example

```
SELECT column 
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '% %';
```

Obviously that's to search for words with spaces by I need to search for those without spaces without using `NOT LIKE`

Comment: Then use `NOT LIKE` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: why you dont want use `NOT LIKE` ?

Comment: btw what is your RDBMS? You can perform a search string for `<space>`

Comment: How come "I need to search for those without spaces without using NOT LIKE"? Please explain!

Answer (score 5):

A simple NOT LIKE Operator should do the trick

```
SELECT column 
FROM table
WHERE column NOT LIKE '% %';
```

Comment: "_I need to search for those without spaces without using NOT LIKE_"

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your RDBMS there are different string functions.

On postgres you can `replace` all spaces and then compare both lengths.

```
SELECT column 
FROM table
WHERE length(column) = length(replace(column, ' ', ''));
```

If after remove all space they still have same length, that mean there wasn't any space when you start.